# Whenever I move an object a circle appears that also affects other objects

Tags: interface, transforms

I am not entirely sure how to even describe the issue I am having. I am making a pretty simple animation with two people and a cop car. Whenever I move one object a large white circle appears around it and anything inside the circle is affected by where and what I do with the object I am trying to move. I have looked all over but I cant seem to find a solution if anyone knows what I am talking about the help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hi, maybe share your file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then edit your question and paste the provided link, it would help others to help you

Comment: I'd just like to point out that [blend-exchange's terms](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/terms/) are [pretty broad](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2413/narrowing-down-terms-of-blend-exchange) on what they can do with your files! Now, the person who owns the site almost certainly has no bad intentions, but personally I don't feel comfortable with it. You don't have to use it if you don't want to. (:

Answer (score 2):

You are probably in "proportional editing object mode" in order to toggle this circle and get back to the standard handler press "O" on keyboard.

Comment: Oh my gosh thank you so much! this was the problem <3